# 'and' keyword in F#

Tags: f#

from the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/keyword-reference:

[image]

it looks like 'and' can be used in the four categories above. With records and constraints, I see the use cases. But can anyone illustrate the uses in let bindings and members?

I see an example in this gist: https://gist.github.com/theburningmonk/3199252 but I'm not sure how it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For let bindings and members, the `and` keyword is used for definining mutually recursive types and functions. A silly example with functions:

```
let rec f x = g x + 1
and g x = f x - 1
```

A silly example with classes:

```
type A() = 
  member x.B = B()
and B() = 
  member x.A = A()
```

The case with classes really covers all possible type definitions, including records and discriminated unions:

```
type A = 
  | Aaa of int 
  | Aaaa of C
and C = 
  { Bbb : B }
and B() = 
  member x.Bbb = Aaa 10
```

Comment: ok, so just like for records. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @Thomas I think so! Unless I'm missing something, I do not think there is any other way of using `and` with members.